# Using WHERE clause twice on same column?

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to select twice from the same column I read a few previously posted questions and some people where suggesting using `T1.` and `T2.` however I'm unsure on how to implement these into this example. So what I'm trying to do is select twice from the `statement_type` column. WHERE the value is either `WTHD` OR `TIP`

```
SELECT * FROM `usr_statements` 
WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `statement_type` = 'WTHD' AND `statement_type` = 'TIP' 
ORDER BY `statement_ref`";
```

The column I'm trying to sort from twice is the `statement_type`.

```
WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `statement_type` = 'WTHD' AND statement_type` = 'TIP'
```

Comment: you can use `OR` among `statement_type` here.

Comment: `WHERE \`username\` = '$username' AND (\`statement_type\` = 'WTHD' OR \`statement_type\` = 'TIP')`

Comment: Easiest to use the "in" statement. Like so... `statement_type` in ('WTHD','TIP')

Comment: Thankyou @FelixPamittan I previously tried OR but without defining the column again. but the suggestion you provided here worked. Thankyou very much.

Comment: @LewisDay, if this question is resolved, please accept one of the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `OR`:

```
WHERE `username` = '$username' AND (`statement_type` = 'WTHD' OR `statement_type` = 'TIP')
```

or use `IN`

```
WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `statement_type` IN('WTHD', 'TIP')
```

Comment: Thankyou! the `IN` is more readable and works perfectly, will be marking as answer shortly. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to sort the same column by using different condition then use `OR`

```
SELECT * FROM `usr_statements` 
WHERE `username` = '$username' AND (`statement_type` = 'WTHD' OR `statement_type` = 'TIP') 
ORDER BY `statement_ref`";
```

If you have more then 3 statement then use `IN` for less the complexity,

```
SELECT * FROM `usr_statements` 
WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `statement_type` IN('WTHD', 'TIP') 
ORDER BY `statement_ref`";
```